# No puedo instalar ChatterBot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

¡Hola! Estoy intentando instalar ChatterBot en Windows 10 desde CMD y me aparece el siguiente error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal'

Igual ya intenté instalar el script PIP con el comando **python get-pip.py** y me indica lo siguiente:

python: can't open file 'get-pip-py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

¿Alguien ha podido solucionarlo?

Comment: ¿Has descargado get-pip.py? Si lo has hecho entonces ejecutalo con `python /ruta/absoluta/de/get-pip.py `

Answer (score 0):

Para ejecutar el script para obtener pip debes poner el archivo con el script en la misma carpeta. Recuerda que cuando utilizamos el CMD de windows o cualquier terminal esta siempre esta ubicada en un directorio por ejempo:

```
c:\usuarios\nancy\desktop\>
```

En este momento tu CMD estara situado en tu escritorio, aunque el nombre de la ruta puede ser diferente la mecanica es la misma. si ejecutas el comando:

```
c:\usuarios\nancy\desktop\>python get-pip.py
```

Es porque en tu escritorio esta el script llamado `get-pip.py` pero si por ejemplo el lugar donde realmente esta es en tus descargas el comando que debieras ejecutar es el siguiente

```
c:\usuarios\nancy\desktop\>python c:\usuarios\nancy\downloads\get-pip.py
```

Para este tipo de problemas es recomendable repetir el proceso de instalacion para hacer una instalacion limpia te recomiendo desinstalar python y volverlo a instalar, pero esta vez de forma correcta.

La forma correcta de instalar python en `windows 10` es atravez de su respectivo wizard encontrado en la pagina de python https://www.python.org/downloads/

Una vez descargado recuerda siempre seleccionar la opcion de instalacion que dice "Agregar al PATH" y el resto de cualquier tiepica instalacion de windows.

Al finalizar la instalacion solo deberas reiniciar tu equipo y ya tendras instalado `python` y `pip`, cuando digo instalado es que ya los podras utilizar en el path.

Realmente el comando para optener pip ya esta obsoleto. `python` te proporciona una instalacion limpia atravez de su instalador encontrado, nuevamente, en su pagina web https://www.python.org/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

yo pude instalar esta versión de chatterbot de esta manera

```
(pip install chatterbot==1.0.4)
```